# Access private method or Variable in Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I want to access Private Method or Variable in Test class.??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Read about and use the [@TestVisble annotation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_testvisible.htm).

From the documentation:

> Use the TestVisible annotation to allow test methods to access private
>   or protected members of another class outside the test class. These
>   members include methods, member variables, and inner classes. This
>   annotation enables a more permissive access level for running tests
>   only. This annotation doesn’t change the visibility of members if
>   accessed by non-test classes.